# How can I transform nested XML elements with xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSL and want to  transform nested XML elements with xslt.
I have a source XML file that contains the following structure:

```
<versions xmlns="urn:stock-quotes">
  <version>
    <mdata>Ma</mdata>
    <state>open</state>
      <version>
          <mdata>Da</mdata>
           <state>open</state>
             <version>
                <mdata>Ga</mdata>
                <state>open</state>
                    <version>
                       ...
                    </version>
              </version>           
       </version>    
  </version>
</versions>
```

How can I transform this XML with xslt?

Comment: At this point, your question makes no sense. You do not "*transform this XML with xslt*". You transform an XML **to something else** - for example, to another XML with a different structure (schema). That part of your question - the expected result of the transformation - is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you write template rules that match each element, where each template rule calls xsl:apply-templates to process its children. But the detail depends rather on what output you want to produce. (Would you post a question asking how to write a Java program to process an input string, without giving any clue what output the program was supposed to produce?)